how to store last_update as date type in mongodb that is conncted to oracle apex
`CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE INSERT_RSS_INFO(
p_source_type           IN NUMBER,
p_last_update           IN DATE
) AS
mapp_json JSON_OBJECT_T;
l_clob CLOB;
l_blob BLOB;
BEGIN
mapp_json := JSON_OBJECT_T();
mapp_json.PUT('source_type', p_source_type) 
mapp_json.PUT('last_update', p_last_update );  
l_clob := mapp_json.TO_CLOB;
l_blob := UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW(l_clob);
INSERT INTO master_rss ( DATA)
VALUES (l_blob);
COMMIT;
END INSERT_RSS_INFO;
/`

Above code is procedure for insert json data in table .
When inserted using form  p_last_update is going as string type in mongodb even i took data type as DATE Or TIMESTAMP  But i need to store as last_update :2022-09-15T21:20:38.000+00:00 which is date type.
And also i took of this p_source_type IN INT or NUMBER OR INTEGER but when inserted data in mongodb , source_type is storing as Double type
Any one please suggest me to solve my issue..?
I tried different way what i have knowledge on it and i changed formatmask for it
I am expecting to store as last_update - date type and source_type-int32 type
